# How do I parse text data from url?

Tags: .net, html, xml, vb.net

We are using the following code to try to parse some text data from the URL 
below:

```
Dim strURL As String = " http://pictures.sprintpcs.com/share.do?invite=VEL42hPQY
Yk34YgLaQPo&shareName=MMS&messageState=RETRIEVED" 

' *** Establish the request 
Dim loHttp As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(strURL), HttpWebRequest) 

' *** Set properties 
loHttp.Timeout = 10000 
' 10 secs 
loHttp.UserAgent = "Code Sample Web Client" 

' *** Retrieve request info headers 
Dim loWebResponse As HttpWebResponse =  DirectCast(loHttp.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) 

Dim enc As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) 
' Windows default Code Page 
Dim loResponseStream As New StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc) 

Dim lcHtml As String = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd() 

loWebResponse.Close() 
loResponseStream.Close() 

LogResponseStream.WriteLine(lcHtml)
```

The problem is that the response we are getting in code is incomplete when 
compared with what actually renders in the browser.  The html we are getting 
shows a javascript function in the body of html where what we really want is the 
result of the function, which includes the data we need to capture.  This is 
confirmed by loading the page in Google Chrome, clicking on the text "100360" 
and choosing "inspect element" which allows us to see the full page response 
with the data we need, specifically the following line:

```
<pre class="pre-longText-wrap">100360</pre>
```

Can anyone help us figure out how to get this "raw" page response?  It may be 
that the script is taking a few seconds to respond and that we are only seeing 
the initial page response.  Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You are more or less out of luck.  The problem is that you **are** getting the raw page response.  If you were a browser, you would then execute the javascript and get the data you want.  But you are not a browser, you are vb.net program, so running that javascript is theoretically possible but probably prohibitively difficult.

Usually the easiest solution for something like this is to actually run the code inside a browser, using javascript, and send the data from there to your server.  It isn't clear if that is feasible in your case.

If not, you need to execute the javascript on the server side in an environment where it can run successfully.  That isn't much fun.  You could script Internet Explorer (yuck!), use Rhino (might be hard to get the environment needed for the script to execute), use node.js (not really solid in Windows yet and it might be hard to get the environment needed for the script to execute), or research your own options from there.

Or you might be able to parse the data out of the raw HTML response, or figure out how to get it.

If sprintpcs gives you an API to get the data you want that would be far easier as well.